# Selenium Ruby - How to find a radio button by name and value?

Tags: selenium, ruby

I have two radio buttons YES and NO, the step on the feature file can pass argument to the method, both radio buttons has the same name so I want to click on the radio button by finding its name and value for example:

```
def licenceStatus(licenceS)
licence = @driver.find_element(name:"licence_status", value:licenceS).click
end
```

The above method works in Watir but not Selenium how do I get this to work?

Comment: The step on the feature file can pass argument like "Yes" or "No" to the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you familiar with css you can use css selector format

```
driver.find_element(:css,"[name='radioBtn'][value='1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath with ruby

```
browser.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@name='licence_status' and @value='licenceS']").click()
```